# Solving a sparse matrix using \ in matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I am trying to solve a problem of the form `Ax=b` in which I have a tridiagonal matrix `A`, and a full vector `b`.

When doing `x=A\b` I get the error message:

```
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be 
inaccurate. RCOND = 3.301735e-150.
```

I have theorised that this may be due to the sparsity of matrix `A`, is there a more efficient built in way of dealing with this in Matlab?

Comment: [`pinv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html) ?

Comment: At some point, there may be no other solution than using some smarter algorithms than what \ gives you. I'd say test `pcg` or `lsqr` first though.

Comment: Neither of those worked, but thanks for the suggestions. I've established that during the iterations it is crashing at a point when `b` is becoming very large, at the point when it crashes it has a norm of 3.2176e+51. Does anyone know if this might have something to do with this?

Comment: Scale the variables to be with std 1 and avg 0. After solving invert the transformation.

Comment: So if I have a while loop that looks like this:

   `while(norm(b,2)>1e-10)`
           `A=C+d*diag(exp(x./(1+0.2*x))./((1+0.2*x).^2));`
           `x=x-A\b;`
           `b=C*x+d*exp(x./(1+0.2*x));`
`end`

how would I do that?